# How long does it take for militia to become good?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Assume I set up squads of 3, give them space to train and set them to a full-time training schedule of 2 dwarfs. How long can it take for my dwarves to become competent at what they are doing? Danger rooms and hunting wildlife aside, is there anything I can do to improve their training?

On a related note, it seems that squad size is inversely proportional to training speed (bigger squads train slower). Is this a bug? Has it been addressed somehow?

Comment: There's always the coinstar machine...!

Comment: It seems to depend on what they're doing. If they never spar, it will take a lot longer for them to level up. I'm not sure what triggers sparring, though, because Ive had militaries that never sparred.

Answer (score 1):

- A sparring sesssion requires all active squad members to be attending. Since dwarfs are often otherweise occupied, a larger squad size results in a lower training speed. This is behavior is known.
- DFHack has a tweak to speed up military training to compensate for that.
- The most important aspects of efficient military training are

  - Squad size
  - Distance to food/water
  - Teaching and weapon skill of the squad leader